# DOM Attributes do not update in Gatsby

Tags: gatsby, react-ssr

I am having a weird issue on the static file after run `gatsby build`.

DOM's attributes (like `className`) could not be updated by listening to the prop change, but not the case of DOM's content, like text or DOM's children.

- Only happening after gatsby-build, aka in SSR

// Verison 1, not working

```
const ThemeProvider = ({ isLight, children }) => {
  return (
    <div className={isLight ? 'light-theme' : 'dark-theme'}> // <- does not change when `isLight` updating
       <h1>{isLight ? 'light-theme' : 'dark-theme'}</h1> // <- changes when `isLight` updating
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

// Verison 2, not working

```
// still having the same issue
const ThemeProvider = ({ isLight, children }) => {
  if (isLight)
    return (
      <div className="light-theme">
       <h1>{isLight ? 'light-theme' : 'dark-theme'}</h1>
        {children}
      </div>
    )
  return (
    <div className="dark-theme">
       <h1>{isLight ? 'light-theme' : 'dark-theme'}</h1>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

// Verison 3, working

```
const ThemeProvider = ({ isLight, children }) => {
  if (isLight)
    return (
      <div className="light-theme">
       <h1>{isLight ? 'light-theme' : 'dark-theme'}</h1>
        {children}
      </div>
    )
  return (
    <section className="dark-theme"> // <-- change to the different DOM, everything works fine
       <h1>{isLight ? 'light-theme' : 'dark-theme'}</h1>
      {children}
    </section>
  )
}
```

Comment: can you share more of your site setup such as gatsby-config & gatsby-ssr? A [minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to say without your minimal example, but I think I might know your likely error.

This will happen when your virtual-DOM on the server (so during SSR) and the virtual-DOM for the hydration (the first run in the browser) is different.

This can happen if you write some code like this:

```js
export default function Comp() {
  let test = 1;
  if (typeof window !== undefined) {
    test = 2;
    // usually you'd be using some browser API or
    // reading query params or something here
  }
  return <a href={test}>not updated</a>;
}
```

What happens is that the DOM from the server will contain `<a href=1>`, and then when React/Gatsby is running `ReactDOM.hydrate` once the browser has loaded, it uses this as the "truth" of what the DOM was when it was rendered on the server.

The only problem is that `ReactDOM.hydrate` will get `<a href=2>` as its result. So when the real `ReactDOM.render` is run afterwards (doing the so-called reconciliation), the virtual DOM will see that `<a href=2>` and `<a href=2>` are the same thing. Even if the actual DOM has `<a href=1>`. So it won't get updated.

---

So how do you fix this? Well, the code above is buggy, you shouldn't write it like that, you can do it in a side-effect, like `useEffect` or `componentDidMount`. So that SSR AND the rehydrate will get the same result.

For our simple example above it could look like:

```js
export default function Comp() {
  const [test, setTest] = useState();
  useEffect(() => { setTest(2); }, [setTest])
  return <a href={test}>updated</a>;
}
```

Comment: I found another answer that explains the same probably better (and just uses a browser API, which would cause the same problem): https://stackoverflow.com/a/56403717/179978

Comment: Indeed, that's the exact issue I was having and Thank you @odinho-velmont for providing a solution for it.