# Gatsby state updates only on development but not on build (production)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am using React context in Gatsby and I have a problem with state changes in the production build. My context is changing React is not automatically updating.

I am thinking my problem is related to this issue: [Unable to update JSX attribute based on URL parameter in a Gatsby app running in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56398811/unable-to-update-jsx-attribute-based-on-url-parameter-in-a-gatsby-app-running-in)

However, I do not get any mismatch errors.

It works well in develop mode, why does it not work in production?

Comment: Since you're not getting any errors, try to clear gatsby cache using `gatsby clean` command then run `gatsby build` and check again.

Comment: @awran5 yes I have done that. I can build no problem but it is not updating the state. I think it has to do with hydrate.

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem:
https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/17914

Two pass rendering

```
class Layout extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { isClient: false }
  }
  render() {
    // can be `div` or anything else, I tried to keep this generic
    return <React.Fragment key={this.state.isClient}> 
      {/*...*/}
    </React.Fragment/>
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isClient: true })
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a quality answer and question. Love the link thank you.